# Adding multiple Contact URLs in SwaggerDoc

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Is it possible to add multiple URLs for the Contact Object based on the Development Environment ?

So for example,

This code in startup.cs

```
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "mycompany awesome API",
                    Description = "ASP.NET Core Web API that acts as a bridge between my company and yours",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "API Support",
                        Email = "apisupport@mycompany.com",
                        Url = new Uri("https://mycompany/Docs"),
                         },
                    License = new OpenApiLicense
                    {
                        Name = "Use under LICX",
                    },
            });
```

Can this support something like

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      Contact = new OpenApiContact
                        {
                            Name = "API Support",
                            Email = "apisupport@mycompany.com",
                            Url = new Uri("https://localhost:44352/Docs"),
                             }
    }
```

If not, is there another way to add external links to swagger based on current environment ?

Thanks in advance